# Invalid key provided to SecureStore. Keys must not be empty and contain only alphanumeric characters, ".", "-", and "_"

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I keep getting this error after changing from `AsyncStorage` to `Expo SecureStore`,

Invalid key provided to `SecureStore`. Keys must not be empty and contain only alphanumeric characters, ".", "-", and "_".

I do not know how exactly to solve it. Could it be the + operator I used to concatenate the

I suspect the error is here or:

```
    import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const prefix = "cache";
const expiryInMinutes = 5;

async function store(key, value) {
  try {
    const item = {
      value,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
    };
    const prefixkey = prefix + key;

    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(prefixkey, JSON.stringify(item));
  } ...
  }
}

async function get(key) {
  try {
    const prefixkey = prefix + key;
    const value = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(prefixkey);
    const item = JSON.parse(value);

    if (!item) return null;

    if (isExpired(item)) {
      await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(prefixkey);
      return null;
    }

    return item.value;
  } catch ...
  }
}

export default {
  store,
  get,
};
```

or here:

```
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const key = "authToken";

const storeToken = async (authToken) => {
  try {
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, authToken);
  } catch (error) ...
  
};

const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    return await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
  } catch ...
  }
};

const getUser = async () => {
  const token = await getToken();
  return token ? jwtDecode(token) : null;
};

const removeToken = async () => {
  try {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
  } catch ...
  }
};

export default { getToken, getUser, removeToken, storeToken };
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is `prefix` defined in your first snippet?

Comment: Its on the 3rd line.

Comment: Thanks.  Where are you using your `store` or `get` methods?  Can you try logging out the keys you're using in your requests and making sure they match your expectations?